# Regex: Find And Replace with new line

Tags: regex

My text editor's Find And Replace function supports regular expressions. For every line that ends with `}`, I want to add a comma to the end of the line. So, I would like to replace all instances where a line `*` ends with `}`, followed by a new line, with the line `*` plus `},` plus the new line. What regular expressions do I need to type in the `Find` and `Replace` fields? Thanks.

Comment: Texworks (Latex editor).

Answer (score 1):

Find: `\}$`

Replace: `\},`

Escape the metacharacter `}`.

Comment: Thanks, but \}$ only seems to find the } on the last line of the documents, and none of the others...

Comment: Strange text editor you're using there. Maybe try finding: `\}(\r\n|\n|$)` and replacing with: `\},$1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace ...

```
\}\n
```

by

```
\},\n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Find: }$
Replace: },
```

But it might depend on the editor.